# How to call a static method from a non activity class?

Tags: android

I am trying to call a method inside my Activity, from a non-activity class. But app force closes. can't figure out how to fix this, so I posted it.

**public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NSOMUHUpdateChecker.checkForUpdates(getBaseContext());
}

public static void boob() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DgrialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

**public class NSOMUHUpdateChecker {**

```
public static void checkForUpdates(Context context) {
    MainActivity.boob();
}
```

**logs:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: nif.nhst, PID: 16378
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nif.nhst/nif.nhst.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
```

Comment: where are you calling this method?

Comment: I am calling a method from main, inside the class, which calls a method inside main.  Main-> Class-> Main

Comment: what is the method and where r u calling

Comment: put all your code here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra check updated question

Comment: you have to pass the context inside that method, because it is null in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is pass a `context` to your non activity class, and then use that context to call activities method, like

```
((MainActivity)context).boob();
```

In your case you can also do some thing like

```
NSOMUHUpdateChecker myobj=new NSOMUHUpdateChecker(MyActivity.this);
```

And then in your class constructor

```
public NSOMUHUpdateChecker(MyActivity act) { 
        act.boob();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `context` to `boob` method

Change

```
public static void boob()
```

To

```
public static void boob(Context context)
```

Comment: i did, it says "Error:(46, 21) error: method boob in class MainActivity cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: well I guess you have no choice - create separate class and paste this method inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply creating a callback interface inside your non activity class and just implement it in main activity.

```
public NonActivityClass {
    public interface Callback {
        void boob();
    }  

    private Callback callerActivity;

    public NonActivityClass(Activity activity) {  
        callerActivity = (Callback)activity;  
    }
    ...  
} 
//call like this
callerActivity.boob();
```

And in main activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    implements IDateCallback {  

    public void boob() {
         //your code!
    }  
}
```